# Integral inequality $\int_0^{\lambda t}(\lambda t-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\le\sup_{z>0}\int_0^ze^{-y}(z-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $0<\alpha<1/2$, $\lambda\ge1$ and $t\in[0,T]$, where $T>0$ is fixed; how can I prove that
$$
\int_0^{\lambda t}(\lambda t-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\le\sup_{z>0}\int_0^ze^{-y}(z-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\le4\;\;\;\;?
$$
The integral on RHS, without the $\sup$ would be smaller than the one on LHS; why can the $\sup$ make this inequality come true? And how can we obtain the numerical bound given by $4$?

Comment: What do you know about $t$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. sorry you're right! I've edited!

Comment: Any relationship between $T$, $\alpha$, and $\lambda$?

Answer (score 0):

The integral on the left can be evaluated explicitly: $$\int_0^{\lambda t} ( \lambda t - y)^{-\alpha} \, dy = \left.- \frac{(\lambda t - y)^{-\alpha + 1}}{-\alpha + 1} \right|_{y = 0}^{y = \lambda t} = \frac{(\lambda t)^{1 - \alpha}}{1 - \alpha}.$$

Unless you can control how large $t$ is permitted to get this can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I know this, in fact $t\in[0,T]$ , where $T>0$ is FIXED, thus $t$ can't be arbitrarily large; I wrote this in my edit.

Comment: What if it is FIXED so that $\dfrac{(\lambda T)^{1 - \alpha}}{1 - \alpha} = 5$?

Comment: The bound with $4$ should be proved with the other integral, the one with the supremum, not with the first one. One once we do this, how can we prove the inequality between the two integrals?

Comment: You can choose $\lambda$, $\alpha$, and $T$ to make the integral on the left equal to $5$. One of these inequalities isn't true.

Comment: You are right. My initial inequality was wider; I'm gonna open another post immediately. However thanks.