# Integral inequality $\int_0^{\lambda t}e^{-y}[(y/\lambda)^{-2a}+(t-y/\lambda)^{-a}]dy\le C[\Gamma(1-2a)+\sup_{z>0}\int_0^ze^{-y}(z-y)^{-a}dy]$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, gamma-function

Let $0<\alpha<1/2$, $\lambda\ge1$ and $t\in[0,T]$, where $T>0$ is fixed; I have to prove that
\begin{align*}
&\frac1{\lambda}\int_0^{\lambda t}e^{-y}[\lambda^{2\alpha}y^{-2\alpha}+\lambda^{\alpha}(\lambda t-y)^{-\alpha}]\,dy\le\\
&\le\lambda^{2\alpha-1}\left[\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-y}y^{-2\alpha}\,dy+\sup_{z>0}\int_0^ze^{-y}(z-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\right]\,\\
&\le\lambda^{2\alpha-1}\left(\frac1{1-2\alpha}+4\right)
\end{align*}
I've noted that $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-y}y^{-2\alpha}\,dy=\Gamma(1-2\alpha)$ but even though [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205771/gamma-function-inequality-gammax-le-frac1x/2205788#2205788) is proved that $\Gamma(1-2\alpha)\le\frac1{1-2\alpha}$, [on this other place](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205721/integral-inequality-int-0-lambda-t-lambda-t-y-alpha-dy-le-sup-z0/2205777?noredirect=1#comment4538071_2205777) is explained that not both inequalities
$$
\int_0^{\lambda t}(\lambda t-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\le\sup_{z>0}\int_0^ze^{-y}(z-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy\le4
$$
can be true, in fact
$$
\int_0^{\lambda t}(\lambda t-y)^{-\alpha}\,dy=\frac{(\lambda t)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}
$$
and we can keep $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ fixed, and find (with $T$ large enough) a $t$ such that $\frac{(\lambda t)^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}=5
$.

So, how can I find a way out? I found these inequalities on a published paper, so it would be a problem if this is not true.

At least, if not both inequality are true, it would be nice to prove the first one.

Comment: In the title, I have replaced "esteem" which has a moral sense by "estimation"

Comment: I alway forget it... thanks!